# how to add the buttons with images on the background image dynamically

Tags: ipad, uiimage

i hav a image back ground and i should able to add some images and buttons with proper images at particular place...

i should able to place these sub images wherever i want on the background image ..dynamically ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the sub images dynamically using UIImage...

Then asign frame for each subImage..

Then add the subImage to mainImage using

```
[mainImage addSubView:subImage];
```